# Finetuning solver for Caffe neural network

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

We're working on object detection in thermal images using neural network with Caffe framework. We use SSD ResNet-10 network available in OpenCV repository as it seems to provide the best performance on Raspberry Pi for our needs (in comparison to MobileNet etc.)

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/dnn/face_detector/solver.prototxt

```
train_net: "train.prototxt"
test_net: "test.prototxt"

test_iter: 2312
test_interval: 5000
test_initialization: true

base_lr: 0.01
display: 10
lr_policy: "multistep"
max_iter: 140000
stepvalue: 80000
stepvalue: 120000
gamma: 0.1
momentum: 0.9
weight_decay: 0.0005
average_loss: 500
iter_size: 1
type: "SGD"

solver_mode: GPU
random_seed: 0
debug_info: false
snapshot: 1000
snapshot_prefix: "snapshot/res10_300x300_ssd"

eval_type: "detection"
ap_version: "11point"
```

Train batch size is 16. Test batch size is 1.

The training process starts at loss 23.4728 and reaches plateau around loss 1.2, learning rate is decreased at iteration 80000 and loss falls down to 0.89. Further decrease continues very slowly to iteration 120000 where loss is around 0.85. Then LR is decreased. Process ends at iteraion 140000 with loss around 0.80 and test evaluation around 0.90.

I noticed that selecting different optimizer gives different results. I tried Nesterov, Adam (with fixed LR) and SGD with different base_lr (0.05) and step size (100000). Are there any recommendation that I could try except of trial&error and waiting 12 hours to compare the results? Reduce/increase batch size? More iterations? Different step sizes?

Adam provides the worst test evaluation. SGD with base_lr reduced to 0.05 and step size 100000 seems to provides the best result now (test eval = 0.94)

[image]